# Tkinter dynamically changing labels with a button and method

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a GUI using Tkinter. I am trying to dynamically update the contents of a message box. Below is my code

def makeDisplay():

```
def updateEntry(): 
    #phonelist[0]
    v = StringVar()
    v.set("additinalText")



def makeWindow() : 
    global  v
    win = Tk()

    frame1 = Frame(win)
    frame1.pack()

    Label(frame1, text= "text argument here").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

    msg = Message(frame1, textvariable = updateEntry) 
    msg.config(bg = "lightgreen", font = ('times', 24, 'italic'))
    msg.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky= W)



    frame2 = Frame(win) 
    frame2.pack()

    b1 = Button(frame2, text= " Update ", command = updateEntry)
    b1.pack(side = LEFT)

    return win  
win = makeWindow()
win.mainloop()
makeDisplay()
```

At the moment i can either set the message once, or leave it blank , but not sure what I am missing to dynamically change it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to *create* `v` in `makeWindow`, and make it `global`:

```
def makeWindow() : 
    global  v
    win = Tk()
    v = StringVar()
```

Then, use it as the `textvariable` for the text field:

```
    msg = Message(frame1, textvariable = v)
```

Finally, access the *existing* variable with `global` in `updateEntry`:

```
def updateEntry(): 
    global v
    v.set("additinalText")
```